# Autocomplete not working on new SWIFT file / Class

Tags: class, swift2, xcode7

I have created a new iOS SWIFT file in XCode and wish to create a very simple class which holds a SKSpriteNode. When doing this, autocomplete and coloring (as set in preferences) is not working on my variables. Sample code:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class dots {

    var dot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "funnyFace.jpg")
    dot.position = CGPoint(x: 100.0, y:100.0)
    addChild(dot)

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the code –  except the variable declaration line  – into a function.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Dots {

    var dot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "funnyFace.jpg")

    func positionAndAddTheDot() {
      dot.position = CGPoint(x: 100.0, y:100.0)
      addChild(dot)
   }
}
```